# 182 hours for a radio station to call in settlers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The game says it will take 183 hours to call in a dweller using a radio station in Fallout Shelter. I used my iOS's clock to forward time. I tried destroying it, but it didn't fix it. Help!

Answer (score 4):

Yeah time glitching breaks radio station, dwellers return to the shelter times, training stats etc.

The only thing it does NOT break is resource gathering from the buildings (simply because you can skip the time when you rush the room) and dwellers going out to the wasteland.

**It can't be fixed. You have to wait for the time to pass and not time glitch meanwhile too.**

Comment: Leave your current radio station there, build a new one, move the dwellers over, then destroy your existing one.  Your new one will have its own clock and just don't build one near the old location.

Answer (score 1):

**Try assigning high Charisma dwellers to the Radio Room, *it should reduce the call time drastically.***

Answer (score -1):

Build a bigger radio room :) It works

Answer (score -1):

183 hours? Use a dweller with high SPECIAL type “C”
It whould be WAY faster 
I go easily because mine is like 2 hours with 15 “C” SPECIAL